# The process cannot access the file

Tags: c#, файлы, потоки-данных

Всем добрый вечер. Когда файл уже создан, всё хорошо. Но если программа сначала создаёт его, вылезает ошибка, что файл используется. Но почему? Процесс тут один, к записи в поток программа переходит после того, как файл создаст.

Вот сама ошибка: "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Tpoc3\Source\Repos\Bachelor-s-Project\TextEditorServer\bin\Debug\files\dd.txt' because it is being used by another process."

```
public void CreateFile(string fileName, string data)
        {
            DirectoryInfo currentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
            if (!currentDirectory.Exists) currentDirectory.Create();
            filePath += @"\" + fileName;
            if (!File.Exists(filePath)) File.Create(filePath);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(data);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ресурс (`FileStream`), который возвращается вызовом `File.Create`, должен быть освобожден:

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath)) 
  using (File.Create(filePath)) { }
```